# Possible to automate message to multiple user submitted email addresses in MailChimp?

Tags: email, share, mailchimp

We're doing a promotion and want to have a visitor share a product with friends (and earn something for doing so)

Basically, John Doe can share a product by submitting 5 of his friends' email addresses via a form that dumps into MailChimp.  MailChimp would then send out an email to each of these friends with a message saying something to the effect of "John Doe has invited you to check out product..."  MailChimp would also send John Doe an email with a promo code in it.

Is something like this even doable in MailChimp?  What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Appreciate any isight... thanks!

Comment: Based on the license agreement, this type of email (known as a transactional email) usually falls out of scope of MailChimp. However, MailChip owns a sister transactional email companion [Mandrill](https://www.mandrill.com/) that has a full API for sending emails just like this. They also support `MX` records to allow for direct domain messaging.

Comment: Yeah, doing things like this at a bulk email ESP is going to get you in trouble pretty quickly, since the people you're emailing didn't give you permission to do that. You'll want to use a transactional service for it instead.